# Call flow for the code - C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am looking into some C code for a microcontroller. I understand most of the code however this piece of the code is puzzling me. 
I am also including relevant definitions for used data types. I have substituted function and variable names for the ease sake.

```
#define COUNT           (2)    
typedef void(*some_type)(void *p);
some_type       some_arr[COUNT] = {NULL, };            

void init(void)
{
    first_function(&second_function);
}

void first_function(some_type cb)
{
    if(some_arr_count < COUNT)
    {
         some_arr[some_arr_count++] = cb;
    }
}

void second_function(void *p)
{
    another_type *req;
    req = (another_type *)p;
    //some other code goes here
}
```

**1.What does this typedef means?**

```
typedef void(*some_type)(void *p);
```

init() function gets called only once and it has only one line of code.

**2.What does this line do?**

```
first_function(&second_function);
```

I searched for the term second_function in the entire project code and it this the only place it appears besides function definition.

**3.So how does second_function get called?**

Comment: You need to read more about function pointers.

Comment: Q1 is duplicate, search for function pointers, and read about them.

Comment: "So how does second_function get called?" - it isn't apparent from the code. it's stored in an array of callbacks, so presumably some other function will call it later.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. I will sure do that. I wasn't sure if the code I have was related to function pointer. That is the sole reason I asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The following `typedef`

   ```
   typedef void(*some_type)(void *p);
   ```

   will define `some_type` as a pointer to function of type `void ()(void *)`.
2. The following statement

   ```
   first_function(&second_function);
   ```

   is a function call, `&second_function`, which is the address of `second_function` , is the argument to `first_function()`.
3. The function `second_function` could be called like this

   ```
   some_arr[some_arr_count](p);
   ```

   `some_arr[some_arr_count]` is a function pointer to `second_function`, which is assigned in `first_function`, and `p` is the argument of `second_function`, which is a pointer to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as suggested in the comments you should go read about function pointers.  I got this ([How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)) from a Google search.

The above link should help to explain answers to question 1 and 2.  For question 3, it is likely that the micro-controller has some built-in mechanism or library function which calls all the function call-backs in `some_arr[COUNT]`, something like the following might work (untested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
{
    if (some_arr[i] == NULL) break;
    (*some_arr[i])(&something_useful);
}
```

Where `something_useful` would be some sort of data that the call-back function could use.

If you are able to search the library code for uses of `some_arr` you might find code to call the `second_function` (although it will no longer be called `second_function`).